# How to specify startup file for Torch REPL

Tags: lua, luajit, torch

I'd like to define some command line convenience functions to be run every time I start the Torch REPL. For example,

`function cl()
    os.execute('clear')
end`

and things of that nature. How can I have functions like this added to the namespace every time I start the REPL?

I web searched "luajit|torch|trepl startup|rc file" but couldn't find any leads on this.

Comment: try set `LUA_INIT=@path/to/startup.lua` env variable. But this will work not only for REPL. Maybe there existst way to detect that you run repl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can alias your th repl to take a default -l parameter:

```
alias thnew='th -lmyadditions '
```

where myadditions.lua is your file to be executed that is placed in your lua path.

Comment: Nice workaround. There should be a space after the "l" by the way.